# What happens to write operations during failover in AWS Multi-AZ RDS mysql instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We can achieve availability for **read operations** in AWS  Multi-AZ RDS mysql instance by using **Read Replica** during failover.But what happens to write operations in such cases?

Comment: For which database engine?

Comment: for InnoDB database engine.

Answer (score 4):

During a Multi-AZ fail-over in MySQL, AWS will change your RDS instance's DNS entry from one server to another. This switch-over takes about a minute or two.

During this time, your application will be unable to connect to the main instance (since the DNS is pointing to the bad server). Your application will receive connection failures. So you cannot read or write.

Once your app receives the new DNS values, it will then connect to the second server where read and write commands will work as expected.

After the fail-over, the original (now theoretically bad) server is replaced and/or fixed and becomes the backup for the new main server.

More information about the fail-over process:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html

Comment: Understood.Is there any way to achieve write availability?

Comment: No. During fail-over, the instance is unavailable until the DNS switches.